# why the Desired Size is not update properly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I have developed a simple application in the WPF platform, my application contains the Zoom slider to increase the zooming level of the page. The desired size gets calculated from the framework is correct without any trouble while I drag the slider at certain speed, but the problem is when I drag the slider at some force  desired size value from the framework is not properly calculated.

I have checked it by calling the `Invalidate-measure()`, but it has not properly resolved my requirement. I checked it by comparing two ratio while dragging

Comment: WPF and UWP are mutually exclusive platforms. Which one is it?